# Error using an array of Java derived classes

Tags: java, derived-class

I am getting an error I don't understand on this code (marked in comments):

```
public class Symbol {
    private String name;
    public Symbol(String name) { this.name = name }
    public String name() { return name; }
}

public class Terminal extends Symbol {
    public Terminal(String name) { super(name); }
}

public class NonTerminal extends Symbol {
    public NonTerminal(String name) { super(name); }
}

public class Rule {
    private NonTerminal lhs;
    private Class<? extends Symbol>[] rhs;

    public Rule(NonTerminal lhs, Class<? extends Symbol>... rhs) {
        this.lhs = lhs;
        this.rhs = rhs;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(lhs.name());
        sb.append(" ->");
        for( int i = 0; i < rhs.length; i++ ) {
            sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(rhs[i].name()); <<<<< ERROR!
            // Get this error: The method name() is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends Symbol>

            // Tried: sb.append(((Symbol)rhs[i]).name());
            // Got error: Cannot cast from Class<capture#1-of ? extends Symbol> to Symbol

        }
        sb.append(';');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The error is given by the Java editor in Eclipse, not at compile time.

**In words**: I want to be able to get a list of Symbols, either Terminals or NonTerminals and be able to use them according to their class.
My understanding, so far, was that `Class<? extends Symbol>` will do for any objet of type `Symbol` or derived from `Symbol`.

So my questions are:

1. Why the public method `name()`, defined in Symbol class, cannot be invoked. In fact all elements in the list are Symbols or derived from Symbol?
2. What is the correct way to invoke `name()` from the array elements?

**EDIT**
I corrected sligthly the code so (with the changes required by the accepted answer) it is a working example. The changes are to change every occurrence of

```
Class<? extends Symbol>
```

to

```
Symbol
```

The test I used to check the answer is:

```
    Terminal t1 = new Terminal("t1");
    Terminal t2 = new Terminal("t2");
    Terminal t3 = new Terminal("t3");

    NonTerminal exp = new NonTerminal("exp");
    NonTerminal nt1 = new NonTerminal("nt1");
    NonTerminal nt2 = new NonTerminal("nt2");
    NonTerminal nt3 = new NonTerminal("nt3");

    Rule r1 = new Rule(exp, t1, nt2, t3);

    Log.v(TAG, "The rule is: " + r1.toString());
```

The log file shows:

> 01-15 10:18:11.335: V/MainActivity(1732): The rule is: exp -> t1 nt2 t3;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class<? extends Symbol>` is a reflection class - it stores a **definition of a class** that's a `Symbol` or one of its sub-classes.

In your example, you want to store **instances** of `Symbol` (or one of its subclasses). Just define your array like this:

```
public class Rule {
    private NonTerminal lhs;
    private Symbol[] rhs;

    public Rule(NonTerminal lhs, Symbol... rhs) {
        this.lhs = lhs;
        this.rhs = rhs;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do what you suggested I get the same error, but somwhere else: `this.rhs = rhs;` (constructor of Rule class) *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<? extends Symbol>[] to Symbol[]*

Comment: The ctor should also be changed - I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: It works, see my enhanced question body. Now I don't understand when and how to use `Class<? extends Symbol>`, but since I have a solution, this will remain a theoretical curiosity.